# NZEC error in Hackerearth problem in java

Tags: java

I'm trying the solve this hacker earth problem https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/basic-programming/input-output/basics-of-input-output/practice-problems/algorithm/anagrams-651/description/

I have tried searching through the internet but couldn't find the ideal solution to solve my problem

This is my code:

```
String a = new String();
String b = new String();
a = sc.nextLine();
b = sc.nextLine();

int t = sc.nextInt();
int check = 0;
int againCheck =0;
for (int k =0; k<t; k++)
{
    for (int i =0; i<a.length(); i++)
    {
        char ch = a.charAt(i);       
        for (int j =0; j<b.length(); j++)
        {
            check =0;
            if (ch != b.charAt(j))
            {
                check=1;                      
            }

        }
        againCheck += check;           
    }
}

System.out.println(againCheck*againCheck);
```

I expect the output to be 4, but it is showing the "NZEC" error

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Welcome. Do you desire **any** solution or are you looking for the most efficient one? Because that's pretty much an easy problem to solve if you don't care about algorithm complexity.

Comment: @Sterconium these hackerXXX things usually have time limits, so a naive algorithm won't work. The link shows that this one has a time limit of 1 second and input length is less than 10000.

Comment: A time limit to give a solution or a time limit for code execution?

Comment: @Sterconium execution. There's also a source code limit and a memory limit in the link. The problem here is that the code doesn't work, so it gives a `Non Zero Exit Code`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirements state<sup>1</sup> that the input is a number (N) followed by 2 x N lines.  Your code is reading two strings followed by a number.  It is probably throwing an `InputMismatchException` when it attempts to parse the 3rd line of input as a number.

Hints:

- It pays to read the requirements carefully.
- Read this article on CodeChef about how to debug a NZEC: https://discuss.codechef.com/t/tutorial-how-to-debug-an-nzec-error/11221.  It explains techniques such as catching exceptions in your code and printing out a Java stacktrace so that you can see what is going wrong.

---

<sup>1 - Admittedly, the requirements are not crystal clear.  But in the sample input the first line is a number.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of *hacker-whatsoever.com* I am going to give two useful things:

- An easier **algorithm**, so you can code it yourself, becuase your algorithm will not work as you expect;
- A **Java 8+ solution** with totally a different algorithm, more complex but more efficient.

**SIMPLE ALGORITM**

In you solution you have a tipical double `for` that you use to check for if every char in `a` is also in `b`. That part is good but the rest is discardable. Try to implement this:

- For each character of `a` find the first occurence of that character in `b`
- If there is a match, remove that character from `a` and `b`.
- The number of remaining characters in both strings is the number of deletes you have to perform to them to transform them to strings that have the same characters, aka anagrams. So, return the sum of the lenght of `a` and `b`.

*NOTE: It is important that you keep track of what you already encountered: with your approach you would have counted the same character several times!*

As you can see it's just pseudo code, of a naive algorithm. It's just to give you a hint to help you with your studying. In fact this algorithm has a max complexity of **O(n^2)** (because of the nested loop), which is generally bad. Now, a better solution.

**BETTER SOLUTION**

My algorithm is just **O(n)**. It works this way:

- I build a [map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html). *(If you don't know what is it, to put it simple it's a data structure to store couples "key-value".)* In this case the keys are characters, and the values are integer counters binded to the respective character.
- Everytime a character is found in `a` its counter increases by 1;
- Everytime a character is found in `b` its counter decreases by 1;
- Now every counter represents the diffences between number of times its character is present in `a` and `b`. So, the sum of the absolute values of the counters is the solution!

To implement it actually add an entry to map whenever I find a character for the first time, instead of pre-costructing a map with the whole alphabet. I also *abused* with lambda expressions, so to give you a very different sight.

Here's the code:

```java
import java.util.HashMap;

public class HackerEarthProblemSolver {
    private static final String a =     //your input string
                                b =     //your input string
    static int sum = 0;                 //the result, must be static because lambda

    public static void main (String[] args){
        HashMap<Character,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();   //creating the map
        for (char c: a.toCharArray()){                      //for each character in a
            map.computeIfPresent(c, (k,i) -> i+1);          //+1 to its counter
            map.computeIfAbsent(c , k -> 1);                //initialize its counter to 1 (0+1)
        }
        for (char c: b.toCharArray()){                      //for each character in b
            map.computeIfPresent(c, (k,i) -> i-1);          //-1 to its counter
            map.computeIfAbsent(c , k -> -1);               //initialize its counter to -1 (0-1)
        }
        map.forEach((k,i) -> sum += Math.abs(i) );          //summing the absolute values of the counters
        System.out.println(sum) 
    }
}
```

Basically both solutions just counts how many letters the two strings have in common, but with different approach.

Hope I helped!

Answer (score 0):

As I've written in other answers as well, it is best to write your code like this when submitting on sites:

```
def myFunction():
    try:
        #MY LOGIC HERE
    except Exception as E:
        print("ERROR Occurred : {}".format(E))
```

This will clearly show you what error you are facing in each test case. For a site like hacker earth, that has several input problems in various test cases, this is a must.

Coming to your question, NZEC stands for : **NON ZERO EXIT CODE**
This could mean any and everything from input error to server earthquake.

Comment: Note: this is Python code.  It won't work in a Java program

Comment: Yes, my mistake. Should have clarified.